# How to list all available search templates in elasticsearch 5.x?

Tags: elasticsearch

With elasticsearch version 2.3.4 it can be done by doing this

```
GET http://localhost:9200/.scripts/_search?
```

What is the equivalent of this in version 5.5.1?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the query as

GET http://localhost:9200/_search/template

This should work

I think templates are not possible but for index, and since search templates are search indexes, you can use

```
GET /.scripts/_search
```

I didn't try but should work.

Comment: Getting 400 status. It asks request body or source parameter.